# For each set of 5 columns, drop the 3rd, 4th and 5th columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am cleaning a pandas dataframe imported from a .csv. It has useful data in the first and second columns, then junk in columns 3-5. This pattern repeats where every 5th column starting from the first and second columns are useful, and every 5th column starting from the third through fifth are junk. I can remove the junk columns using the code below:

```
df1 = df.drop(columns=df.columns[4::5])
df1 = df1.drop(columns=df1.columns[3::4])
df1 = df1.drop(columns=df1.columns[2::3])
```

Is there a solution to do this all in one line?

Comment: Perhaps address the root of the problem? Where is all this extraneous non-"useful" data coming from? Is it possible to leave it out from the get-go?

Comment: I would definitely take ddejohn's suggestion here and investigate why you have to skip these columns in the first place

Comment: @ddejohn The csv with the extraneous columns is an output from my customer's system. Unfortunately, I don't have any control over it.

Comment: @KevinColeman if you're reading the csv into Pandas you can just select which columns you want -- check out [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think three lines is fine. The code won't get any clearer or faster from putting it all on one line.

Of course, you can always do:

```
columns = df.columns[:]
df1 = df.drop(columns=columns[4::5]).drop(columns=columns[3::5]).drop(columns=columns[2::5])
```

which I think also makes it clearer you intend to drop the fifth, fourth and third column every five columns.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean indexing the columns using `numpy` could be useful

```
import numpy as np
# select 1st and 2nd columns of every 5 columns
df1.loc[:, np.isin(np.arange(df1.shape[1]) % 5, [0,1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate indexes in an easy way:

```
>>> c = df.columns
>>> df.drop(columns=np.r_[c[2::5], c[3::5], c[4::5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, ::5], df.iloc[:, 1::5]], axis='columns')
```

That will change the column order, but with well-named columns, that shouldn't matter.